# Using a mixture of SSIS, asp.NET and wget functions to extract, transform and load data to a web page

Tags: asp.net, xml, ssis

This is more of a question to check feasibility.

Ultimately what I'd like to do is:

**1)** Create an asp.NET page with one string parameter field

**2)** Have that parameter field pass to an SSIS package that looks at (for simplicity let's say an XML data page with the parameter variable being in the URL)

**3)** Have that SSIS package take the data from that variable XML page

**4)** Load the data into a cache table

**5)** Display the live data (would the live data also need to be put into a 'live table'?) on the next page to be used for in-depth analysis (using crystal or component art or similar)

From an end user perspective they're logging onto a website, typing in a specific string (let's say carrots) and then SSIS goes away and gets carrot data from our third party XML source and gives a detailed analysis of carrots on the next page with the data gathered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple obstacles You may encounter using SSIS in this scenario:

1. SSIS packages require constant metadata which means that your source (fetched XML) and destination (table) should not change underlying metadata - XML should have exactly the same schema and destination table columns should not be altered, also.
2. Passign data from SSIS package to ASP.NET page is tricky: storing data in 'live table' (tricky to differentiate row id to fetch from table)
3. Executing SSIS package requires permissions
4. How to store connection strings in SSIS package in safe manner
5. asp.net user (impersonated or not) has to have permissions to execute package and then SSIS connection managers with Integrated Security login might fail
6. if You decide to execute package thru job, asp.net user must have permissions to execute package (then use proxy/credentials for job to set appropriate permissions inside SSIS package)
7. is this list long enough!? :)

I strongly suggest to avoid SSIS in this simple scenario because it adds additional overhead layer for implementation and maintenance. Why don't You write .NET code to fetch XML and process it. You can even skip storing results to 'live table' this way.

Comment: Thanks for the response, very helpful. I had completely overlooked permissions, that's going to be near impossible with a public service anyway.

Comment: My only hesitation with fetching XML and HTTP data is that I'm unfamiliar with how to process and use the data once I have it, I'm used to doing analysis on stored data (hence why SSIS seemed natural and safe). Is it quite simple to fetch and then analyse the data? A lot of analysis tools which I'd need to use to produce presentable and 'pretty' statistics seem to require a proper data source structure.

Comment: Correct me if I oversimplify your scenario: You need to fetch XML from some URI, extract some data from it (elements/attributes, ...) and show it to user? All operations in your question are not difficult to implement in pure .NET. Actually, You can find all needed code parts on Internet except your logic to extract data from XML to some in-memory structure in order to present it to user (because probably no one knows the schema of your XML and what exactly do You need to read from XML). If You need further assistance don't hesitate to post additional comments or questions.

Comment: Of course, if You post additional questions on stackoverflow, put link to them here in comments so we can track your progress and help.

Comment: One more remark: SSIS is not intended for analysis but for ETL (Extract, Transform, Load). So I wrote my answer and comments in that manner: that You need to transform XML to some in-memory structure (classes or so) or write it to database table if You want.

Comment: I love SSIS but don't think this is a strong contender for using it. Beyond Filip's excellent reasons, I'd add in the start up/validation time for SSIS is probably not acceptable for a web page. Is there a reason you don't want to load all the available XML files into a table(s)? I would think that would provide optimal response time to the user and allow you to use SSIS for getting that data in there.